# Not able to get admin.addPeer() run

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, testnets, windows

I have installed ethereum(go-eth) in a folder named "blockchain". In that "blockchain" folder, i have 2 more folders, 'node2' and 'node3'.

**Step 1:**

I have used the following genesis.json file and stored the same json file in both folders:

```
{
"nonce": "0x0000000000000042",
"timestamp": "0x0",
"parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"extraData": "0x0",
"gasLimit": "0x8000000",
"difficulty": "0x400",
"mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"coinbase": "0x3333333333333333333333333333333333333333",
"alloc": {

 }
}
```

saved the file with name "genesis.json"

**Step 2:**

For initializing the genesis block i executed the following commands from 2 different command prompts:

terminal 1(node2):

```
geth init "C:\Rahul1306\blockchain\node2\genesis.json" networkid 100
```

terminal 2(node3):

```
geth init "C:\Rahul1306\blockchain\node3\genesis.json" networkid 100
```

Genesis block gets initialized and space is allocated to me, for both nodes.

**Step 3**

Now i run the following commands to get "chaindata" and other files in respective nodes:

terminal 1(node2)

```
geth --identity "node2" --ipcdisable --rpc --rpcport "8001" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir "C:\Rahul1306\blockchain\node2" --port "30304" --nodiscover --ipcapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3" --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,personal,admin" --autodag -verbosity 6 --networkid 100 --nat "any" console
```

terminal 2(node3)

```
geth --identity "node3" --ipcdisable --rpc --rpcport "8002" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir "C:\Rahul1306\blockchain\node3" --port "30305" --nodiscover --ipcapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3" --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,personal,admin" --autodag -verbosity 6 --networkid 100 --nat "any" console
```

All  the required files are added in both the folders

**Step 4**

I use the following command in both the terminals to fetch their enode address:

```
admin.nodeInfo
```

I receive the following addresses:

node2:

```
enode://b94f327b518b68f33304078352f7b74cd6290c7601f42ec5cc5f4f50813de2
489171769124f93a4047f1e55a49aee6e5a45869b40bb0b18e395acd0bb40b625e@[::]:30305
```

node3:

```
enode://b94f327b518b68f33304078352f7b74cd6290c7601f42ec5cc5f4f50813de2
489171769124f93a4047f1e55a49aee6e5a45869b40bb0b18e395acd0bb40b625e@[::]:30305
```

**Step 5**

Now in order to connect these nodes/ attach them to the private network, I use the following command:

Here i am trying to add node3 as a peer of node2. So the following command is executed on terminal 1 ,i.e on node2 terminal.
**Notice, i have changed '[::]' with localhost address,i.e '127.0.0.1'**

```
admin.addPeer("enode://b94f327b518b68f33304078352f7b74cd6290c7601f42ec5cc5f4f50813de2
489171769124f93a4047f1e55a49aee6e5a45869b40bb0b18e395acd0bb40b625e@127.0.0.1:30305?di
scport=0")
```

Now, here is where the problem occurs. I should receive a boolean value, 'true'. Both the geth consoles are working and i execute this command and i receive the following error:

```
(anonymous): Line 1:15 Unexpected token ILLEGAL (and 2 more errors)
```

I am not able to understand where i went wrong. So, i need to be able to add the above two nodes as peers in private blockchain network. Please help!

Comment: It is a good practice that accepting the answer as correct if it helped you resolved the issue. That is the whole point of SE none of the answers for your questions are marked as correct. FYI, if youre not aware of it.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 2:**

Use `--datadir` while initializing the genesis file. And the command should be `--networkid` not `networkid`

**Step 3:**

Post your output for the commands so that we can check whether you successfully started the private blockchain with the custom genesis block.

**Step 4:**

Your enode information is wrong. According to your commands in Step 3, both the nodes should have different enode URIs and node 2 should have port 30304. Either you posted the wrong output or you created only one node.

**Step 5:**

You don't need the `?discport=0` in the end of enode URI.